# Ruby .to_sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

In the .to_sentence method, How can I get the last_word_connector to output an HTML string?

For example:

```
locations.to_sentence last_word_connector: '<br />'
```

I want the `<br />` to actually be interpreted. I have tried adding `.html_safe` on the end but to no avail.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. `["a", "b", "c"].to_sentence(last_word_connector: '<br />')` produces `"a, b<br />c"`, which is valid string of html. What exactly do you want it to produce?

Comment: I want the <br /> to be interpreted and not actually output on the page. For example If I set the connector to be <b>HELLO</b>. The output would be the word HELLO in bold and not '<b>HELLO</b>' written out on the page as that would be silly.

Comment: @Flambino - Doing so now, What do I do on the questions where comments have been posted and no full answers and should just be left at that? or ones without answers for that sort of need closing and are finished with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to tell the view that the string is "safe" to insert (i.e. it should be inserted as-is - not escaped):

```
<%= locations.to_sentence(last_word_connector: '<br />').html_safe %>
```

The `html_safe` method returns a string that's marked as, well, html-safe. So it won't be escaped.

Use with caution. The reason Rails escapes string by default is that it makes html- and javascript-injection attempts harmless. So if you're not completely sure of the content of `locations`, then be careful.

Comment: Just FYI, there is now an html-safe-aware version of `to_sentence` https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-to_sentence but it's a view helper and not an add on to the Array class.